# Reference to undefined variable env" error running Eclipse with TestNG/Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing, testng

Getting the error 'Launching [testname]' has encounted a problem. Reference to undefined variable environment

Background: I have a test suite installed that I did not create or use before. When I initially run the test suite, there are no errors. I copied the body of a new test case, right clicked and created and named a new class and made one small change to try to teach myself how to run this test suite. I am new in this QA department and coming from Robot Framework/Python to a Page Object Model Java environment using Eclipse, Maven, TestNG. I have not made any path changes or environment changes except for trying to put maven in my path after mvn -version came up with nothing. My lead says that I shouldn't even have to screw around with maven because it worked when I ran the original set of test cases.

How do I figure out what undefined variable environment they're talking about? All the variables are defined in my program and the environment doesn't seem to be a problem with anyone else.

Comment: Did you try updating the project? Right click on the project name->Maven->Update project, then try running it again

Comment: In menu `Run->Run Configurations` you can view settings of a given suite. It's hard to tell from your description if you're talking about Maven or TestNG suite. Nevertheless on `Arguments` tab you can use 'Variables` in a form of `${some_name}`, on `Classpath` - class path variables and on `Environment` - environment vars. Compare values on these tabs between the two suites, maybe you could find the difference there.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the value to arguments in the form like "variableName=${value}", please try "variableName=${value}"

Comment: Can you provide additional information - why your solution is working.